# In what order are several properties auctioned by the bank?

Tags: monopoly

When you go bankrupt to the bank, all of your properties are returned to the bank and auctioned.

Rule :

> Should you owe the Bank, instead of another player, more than you can
>   pay (because of taxes or penalties) even by selling off buildings and
>   mortgaging property, you must turn over all assets to the Bank. In
>   this case, the Bank immediately sells by auction all property so
>   taken, except buildings.

Source : [The Rules of Monopoly - Hasbro](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf)

If you have surrendered several properties to the bank, in what order are they auctioned, one at a time: by order of value, or randomly?

Since the rules don't specify this, in the answer, I would appreciate an authoritative quote (e.g. tournament experience, book author), not just an opinion or house rule.

Comment: I grant that the wording is ambiguous, but the intent seems to be that the property is auctioned off as a single lot, not as individual pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following ruling was received from Hasbro, publisher of Monopoly and organiser of International Monopoly Tournaments. I have therefore completely rewritten this answer.

**My questions to Hasbro :**

> The rules of Monopoly state that when a players goes bankrupt to the
>   bank, the player turns all assets over to the Bank. The Bank then
>   auctions off these properties.
>
> Are all of the properties auctioned off at once as a single lot?
>
> If they are auctioned one at a time, in what order are they auctioned? By value or randomly selected?

**Hasbro agent's answers:**

> *1. Are all of the properties auctioned off at once as a single lot?*
>
> No. All properties should be auctioned off one at a time.
>
> *2. If they are auctioned one at a time, in what order are they auctioned?
>       By value or randomly selected?*
>
> No specific order needed . The banker can randomly select. I have
>   also included the proper way to hold a Monopoly Auction just in case
>   it's needed.   There is nothing terribly special with the process of
>   holding the auction, just a few simple rules.
>
> When a property comes up for auction, whether a player declines to
>   purchase or a player goes bankrupt, the banker holds the auction.
>
> There is no minimal bid so the starting price will always be $1 and
>   the property will goes to the highest bidder and the price is binding.
>   So if a player bids more than they have they can unintentionally
>   bankrupt themselves during the auction.
>
> The auctioned property cannot be mortgaged by the highest bidder in
>   order to complete the purchase.
>
> Important Note:  All players can participate in property auctions –
>   this includes the banker, any players who may be in jail, and the
>   person who originally declined to purchase the property in the first
>   place.

Comment: Interesting, that different sources disagree on this subject.  
There are so many versions of monopoly, but still no complete set of rules without mismatches or gaps.

Comment: I completely replaced the previous answer with the own from Hasbro.

Comment: The Hasbro agent's answer may be out of date. The rulebook on Hasbro's website (copyright 2017) specifies the bidding starts at $10, not $1, though players may increase the bid by $1.